# Cannot RDP to another Ubuntu box

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I have Ubuntu 15.10 running on my desktop PC and my laptop. On the desktop PC I have enabled sharing in Desktop Sharing Preferences:

[image]

Next I am trying to use remmina client to connect to Ubuntu on my desktop PC from my laptop. On my laptop I am doing a quick connect where I am using the hostname for the desktop pc in:

```
cat /etc/hostname
ubuntu-macmini
```

Where I have discovered that I need to specify the hostname followed by **.local** So In Remmina I specify:

[image]

When I do that I get this screen:

[image]

When I enter my user and pass it connects but after a short while the remote desktop simply terminates by itself - I never get to see the actual desktop on the remote server.

There are some alternatives from the above menu:
[image]

But I have not had any success with selecting any of those either.

Any ideas?

SOLUTION: I manged to solve the problem by installing a VNC server on the remote machine and then select the following in Remmina:

[image]

It will auto populate the configuration and connection worked fined afterwards. So the trick was to select:

```
VNC - Virtual Network Computing
```

And simply browse for the VNC server.

Comment: What RDP server are you using on the remote machine?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please see my updated post with more details. If that is not enough what are the steps I need to perform to determine the RDP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is:

1. Install VNC server on remote machine.
2. In Remmina on client machine select **VNC - Virtual Network Computing**
3. Next browse to available VNC servers and select the one you just configured. Finally connect.

See:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set your desktop client to listen on a specific port using the Remmina client.  It has an option to do that.

When you go to create a new connection with the little document/plus symbol. Then in the drop down "Protocol" select "VNC Incoming Connection"

Then you can more tightly control the VNC server.

VNC works better on Linux then RDP.

Comment: Just any port, e.g. 5555? And I don't really understand that I should specify a listen port on the client. Is it not the server that should be listening for incoming connections? I assume the above requires that a VNC server is running on the server on port 5555?

Comment: You can use netstat -vaun to see ports currently used.  Just don't make it one that is being used and you are good.  I think you can also use the default port which is 5900 for tightVNC.

Comment: See edited post. I made it work using the: VNC - Virtual Network Computing

Comment: awesome bud mark this as the answer then.  Glad you got everything working.

Comment: Well actually I did not managed to solve the problem based on your suggestion: "VNC Incoming Connection". I had to to experiment with "VNC - Virtual Network Computing"  instead to get it working. If I accept you answer it might cause some confusion. Is it possible to accept my own question as an answer? You definitely pointed me in the right direction though.

Comment: yeah you can write an answer and then accept your own answer, but if the VNC Server machine is Ubuntu you don't need to install anything.  It comes default with vino server.  If you did as I suggested you can do it without any additional install when working from Ubuntu to Ubuntu.